# Remove neo4j inactive labels from database

Tags: neo4j

What is the method for removing inactive, unwanted node labels in a Neo4j database (community edition version 2.2.2)?

I've seen this question in the past but for whatever reason it gets many interpretations, such as clearing browser cache, etc.

I am referring here to labels actually contained in the database, such that the REST command

```
GET /db/data/labels
```

will produce them in its output. The labels have been removed from any nodes and there are not active constraints attached to them.

I am aware this question has been asked in the past and there is a cumbersome way of solving it, which is basically, dump and reload the database. The dump command doesn't even contain scattered commit statements and thus needs to be edited before executing it back. Of course this takes forever with big databases. There has to be a better way, or at least there is a feature in the queue of requirements waiting to be implemented. Can someone clarify?

Comment: I am sorry for having to introduce a new question to the already existing pool of similar ones. My stackoverflow reputation isn't high enough for me to comment on those other questions, the point I'm trying to make is that these are DB contained labels, having other users point at inactive labels is distracting at most.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you delete the last node with a certain label - as you've observed - the label itself does not get deleted. As of today there is no way to delete a label.

However you can copy over the datastore in offline mode using e.g. [Michael's store copy tool](https://github.com/jexp/store-utils) to achieve this.

The new store is then aware of only those labels which actually are used.

Comment: Will try this and will update the result here. Thanks for the tip. However let it also be clear (according to one of the issues in github) that this tool won't take care of indexes and/or constraints, as those need to be recreated manually. Great tool in concept though.

Comment: I used Michael's tool and was able to properly clean up a database by copying to another one. Works very well, and it doesn't take forever as if trying to dump the content in a script. Thanks for the tip!